# What are the stable cohomology classes of the "orthogonal groups" of finite abelian groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, orthogonal-groups

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group, and equip it with a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $\langle,\rangle : A \times A \to \mathrm{U}(1)$. Then you can reasonably talk about the "orthogonal group" $O(A,\langle,\rangle)$, i.e. the automorphisms of $A$ which preserve $\langle,\rangle$.

Actually, when $A$ has even order, the most standard version of "orthogonal group" is to choose a quadratic refinement $q : A \to \mathrm{U}(1)$ of $\langle,\rangle$, i.e. a quadratic function such that $q(a_1 a_2) / q(a_1)q(q_2) = \langle a_1,a_2\rangle$, and to ask for the group $O(A,q)$ of automorphisms preserving $q$. (When $A$ has odd order, there is a unique quadratic refinement, and so the two notions agree. In general, the quadratic refinements form a torsor for $\hom(A, \mathbb{Z}/2)$.) I can ask my question for both versions of $O(A)$, but in fact the one I care about is the "nonstandard" $O(A,\langle,\rangle)$ when $A$ has order a power of $2$.

**I am interested in understanding the low $\mathbb{Z}/2$-cohomology of $O(A,\langle,\rangle)$.**

I specifically want to know about classes which are "stable", but I am having trouble saying precisely what I want "stable" to mean. Certainly if I have two groups $A, A'$ each equipped with nondegenerate symmetric bilinear forms, then I only care about the image of restriction along $O(A) \subset O(A) \times O(A') \subset O(A \times A')$. But I expect that if there is a stronger notion of "stability", then I only care about those classes.

Comment: Abelianisations you can probably get from Hahn-O'Meara.